# If I launch VNC server on localhost:1, will any application I open from that machine automatically use the VNC as its X server?

Tags: vnc

If I launch a VNC server on some machine, from then on, will any GUI application I launch use the VNC server as its X window system, or do I have to specify to use the VNC server for every application I open after it? If so, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VNC server does not do GUI. All it does is mirror the server's
screen to the remote client, so any GUI application launched on the server
will be using the server's X Windows.

You don't need to specify anything - everything is done automatically.

Comment: Thank you. So if I install and run vncserver, do I have to specify a desktop environment to launch in the xstartup file, or does the system (Ubuntu) know a default DE which vnc can start by default?

Comment: VNC does not start anything - it only mirrors the server's screen. It's not an alternate display, there's only one display which is the server's.

Comment: Ok, so all I need to do is install vncserver with no special configuration and then connect Firefox to my DISPLAY environmental variable (I am researching now how to find the name of my display) and then if I run Firefox it’ll appear in VNC? Do you know how I find my display name?

Comment: I need to execute this command to view Firefox, I believe: $ export DISPLAY=yourmachine.yourdomain.com:0.0

Comment: xrandr —query says “Cannot open display”. I’m in Ubuntu Server. How can I connect it to a display (for my VNC)?

Comment: See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display).